# Add image using Prawn, got error: Prawn::Errors::UnsupportedImageType, PNG uses unsupported interlace method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I used Prawn to create pdf file, I want to put the logo in file. I have looked at this site [Creating pdf](http://www.idyllic-software.com/blog/creating-pdf-using-prawn-in-ruby-on-rails/) to reference how to add image.

This is my code in `ExamResultPdf.rb` file to generate pdf:

```
  def initialize(exam, view)
    super(top_margin: 70)
    @exam = exam
    exam_number # line 9, I removed codes are not relevant
  end

  def exam_number
    logo_path = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo_hoasen.png"
    image logo_path, height: 200, width: 200
    text "Examination Result \##{@exam.id}", size: 30, style: :bold
  end
```

But when I go to page `/result.pdf`, it has error:

```
Prawn::Errors::UnsupportedImageType in ExamsController#result
PNG uses unsupported interlace method

# Trace
app/pdfs/exam_result_pdf.rb:18:in `exam_number'
app/pdfs/exam_result_pdf.rb:9:in `initialize'
app/controllers/exams_controller.rb:43:in `new'
app/controllers/exams_controller.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in result'
app/controllers/exams_controller.rb:40:in `result'
```

My `exams_controller`:

```
def result
    @exam = Exam.find(params[:id])
    @general_exam = GeneralExam.where(id: @exam.general_exam_id).first
    @topic_questions = TopicQuestion.where(general_exam_id: @general_exam.id)
    @exam_result = ExamResult.where(exam_id: @exam.id, user_id: @exam.user_id).first

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = ExamResultPdf.new(@exam, view_context) # line 43
        send_data pdf.render, filename: "exam_result_#{@exam.id}",
                                  type: "application/pdf",
                           disposition: "inline"
      end
    end
  end
```

So I want to ask why I got this error, Prawn is not support png file? How can I put image in pdf file?

**Update**

I have used `jpg` or `jpeg` file, but it did not work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After one hour search google, I have not found the problem. Then I try to convert png file to jpg file. I used [Online Image Converter](http://www.coolutils.com/online/image-converter/) to convert png to jpg file. After image was converted, I used the jpg file:

```
logo = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo_hoasen.jpg"
image logo, width: 240, height: 75, position: :left
```

And now it worked correctly. It seems the problem was because my png image file.

Answer (score 6):

There are many types of PNG - the vast majority will work with prawn, but a few won't.

The easiest option would be to convert it to a JPG or re-save it as a PNG that isn't interlaced.

Comment: See the following StackOverflow topic for how to convert a png to uninterlaced:
[How to de-interlace png files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742548/how-to-de-interlace-png-files)