# How to de-interlace png files?

Tags: png

For Slick to load png files without a warning, they cannot be interlaced.  I don't have photoshop, and I don't want to get it.  Is there an alternative way to de-interlace images, perhaps through Paint.net plugins?  I'm on a Windows machine, only mentioning this because there is a multitude of de-interlacing programs that only work on Mac or Linux.

Comment: Just open it with practically any Image Editor/Viewer (eg: xnview) and save it as non-interlaced.

Comment: @leonbloy as it turns out MS Paint saves PNG files as non-interlaced...  So now if I want to make a new file I have to save it in MS Paint instead of Paint.net.  do you know if there are any ways to save as non-interlaced in Paint.net?

Comment: Paint.net does not save PNG as interlaced.

Comment: Strange, perhaps it's just this image or something...  No, once I saved it in Paint.NET it gave problems again.  It's also entirely possible that it isn't actually interlacing, it may be the bits but I'm saving images as 8 bit.

Comment: Are you sure it's interlaced? http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/26064-non-interlaced-png/ Test with http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/

Comment: It's 8 bit, non - interlaced...  Let me see what it says if I do MS Paint's version.

Comment: On the Paint.NET one it says it's "8 bits/pixel, paletted", on MS Paint it says "8 bits/sample, truecolor + alpha"

Answer (score 18):

Use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) - it's not fast, but is at least cross-platform.

```
magick convert -interlace none interlaced.png uninterlaced.png
```

Comment: Thanks, works great for me. I had an issue with interlaced PNG files in connection with asciidoctor pdf generation.

**Hint**: For me the complete command was `magick convert -interlace none interlaced.png uninterlaced.png`.

Comment: I too needed to use asciidoctor-pdf and was facing the same issue. I installed 'ImageMagick-6.9.12-Q16-HDRI' (latest version) and found the new command to convert interlaced to uninterlaced png as below (we no longer need 'magick' at the start of the command):                                                    
convert -interlace none interlaced.png uninterlaced.png

Answer (score 0):

Building upon [pobrelkey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19742588/674064) and [mentalo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742548/how-to-de-interlace-png-files#comment99328663_19742588), you can use ImageMagic's [`mogrify` command](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify) to convert the image in-place:

(**Warning**: The following will *overwrite* `some-image.png`.)

```
magick mogrify -interlace none some-image.png
```

This also allows to convert multiple image files at once:

```
magick mogrify -interlace none image1.png image2.png image3.png
```

```
magick mogrify -interlace none *.png
```